# Why does parseFloat(0.15) % 0.05 return 0.04999999999999999?

Tags: javascript

This code returns: 0.04999999999999999

```
var number = parseFloat(0.15);
console.log(number % 0.05);
```

Why?

Here is a plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/fYa4ZpvNj3xTvgNHx0pj?p=preview

Comment: `parseFloat` parses a string to a number. What's the point of using it on a number?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Comment: In my case "0.15" comes from user input which is a string and I don't know if the user actually entered a number or just some random string.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point math is actually only as good as the bit width representation.  For instance, 0.1 is actually 0.100000010000001.

Comment: The precision is not so low. `0.1 < 0.100000010000001 === true`